# Produce State Frequencies and Entropy Index for a Particular Variable

Tags: traminer

I am able to generate separate plots from my data set (`DISDARAE`) for different variables (`GENDER`, `RACE`) such as

```
seqIplot(DISDATAE.seq, border = NA, group = DISDATAE$GENDER, sortv = "from.start")
seqIplot(DISDATAE.seq, border = NA, group = DISDATAE$RACE, sortv = "from.start")
```

How do I generate separate state frequency and entropy tables for each variable?
I used this syntax for the entire data set: `seqstatd(DISDATAE.seq[, 1:4])`, but unable to create one for separate variables

Answer (score 0):

Just use `by`. I illustrate using the `mvad` data shipping with `TraMineR`

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
# creating the state sequence object
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 15:86])

## Distributions and cross-sectional entropies by sex
by(mvad.seq, mvad$male, seqstatd)
```

Hope this helps.